# Add increasing Tags to NSPopUpMenu programatically

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I create a NSPopUpMenu dynamic from the content of a textfile. Thats working good so far. The problem is, that I can´t safe the last state of the Menu to the Defaults plist. Every time I start the App again the Menu is back to default and not the last selected item. Any ideas how I could add tags increasing for all Items so that I could save it to Defaults?

```
func check_for_games() {
        let filePath = "/private/tmp/steam_games"
        if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath)) {
            let location = NSString(string:"/private/tmp/steam_games").expandingTildeInPath
            self.pulldown_menu.item(withTitle: "")?.isHidden=true
            let fileContent = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: location, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            for (_, games) in (fileContent?.components(separatedBy: "\n").enumerated())! {
                self.pulldown_menu.menu?.addItem(withTitle: games, action: #selector(ViewController.menuItemClicked(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
            }
         } else{
            return
        }
}
```

Comment: Is the app sandboxed? If yes you don't have access to `/private...`. By the way `NSString(string:"/private/tmp/steam_games").expandingTildeInPath` is pointless. There is no tilde at all. Basically don't use `NSString` in Swift. And `enumerated()` is also pointless if you don't need the index.

Comment: Do you want to add the index as tag and save the tag instead of the index? Can't you save the title of the selected item? Have you tried setting the tag?

Comment: Its not sandboxed and the menu has all entries from the textfile. Thats working fine.

Saving of the title of the selected item works too., But there is now way to restore this item after restarting the app. I saved it programatically. But connecting the Menu via the Inspector does not work. It seems it does not work general with a adynamically created Menu.

Tags are the only thing which could work in this case and thats the reason why i asked to add a tag to every item via swift.

Comment: Why can't you select the item with the title, does the title change? How do you link the tag to the title? What is preventing you from setting the tag? Is `NSPopUpMenu` the same as `NSPopUpButton`? Is the pop-up button in pull-down mode?

Comment: If the index is the tag then you can use `indexOfSelectedItem` and `selectItem(at:)` instead of `selectedTag()` and `selectItem(withTag:)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know why but now the selection with item title is working:

`self.pulldown_menu.selectItem(withTitle: "Nebuchadnezzar (1157220)")`

I could swear yesterday it does not work. Anyway ... thanks.